# reconfirming new email with devise in rails does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I am trying to manually reconfirm an email in the console.  First, the user looks like this:

```
<Student id: 75, email: "laura81392@vilt.edu", 
  encrypted_password: "$2a$10$vdbbRPmAu/cZJy7jOPfXLI54KBMRZu5...", 
  reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil,
  sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, 
  current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, profile_name: "lily", 
  first_name: "Laura", last_name: "Lil", how_did_you_hear: "Other", 
  created_at: "2014-08-29 16:22:16", updated_at: "2014-08-29 17:02:22", 
  type: "Student", school_id: 16, company: nil, title: nil, wants_mail: true,
  confirmation_token: "056b347e438a5b3b7011af29e6e6795d2cb090b47ff3d67f...", 
  confirmed_at: "2014-08-29 16:24:19", confirmation_sent_at: "2014-08-29 17:02:22",
  unconfirmed_email: "laura@ldog123.com">
```

I run

```
User.find(75).confirm!
```

But it does not change the user at all.  The command returns nil. The User does not change at all.  How do I reconfirm the email?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable)

If you're trying to skip confirmation then use:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.email = "new_email@gmail.com"
user.skip_reconfirmation!
user.save
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer my question.  The new email address is still listed as the unconfirmed_email and the email address is still the old email

Comment: I think the way it works is that you set the new email, skip confirmation, and then save.

Comment: Nope, doing skip_confirmation! just returns the time and isn't changing anything about the user.

Comment: I fixed the code. `skip_reconfirmation!` will do the trick. I tested this locally and it works just fine.